# PHP/Laravel: How to insert a new json field when creating JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am returning JSON to my frontend like this:

```
    public function newFlavorOrders()
    {
        $orders = request()->user()->ordersPaid;
        return response()->json(['flavor_orders' => $orders]);
    }
```

and right now, that returns this to the frontend:

```
{ orders: [
   {
     color: "Green"
     size: "Large",
     order_products: [ {'itemNum': 3, 'imgUrl': "zera.jpg"}, {'itemNum': 5, 'imgUrl': "murto.jpg"} ]
   },
   {
     color: "Blue"
     size: "Large",
     order_products: [ {'itemNum': 3, 'imgUrl': "mcue.jpg"}, {'itemNum': 5, 'imgUrl': "cloa.jpg"} ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to alter the controller PHP function to add a field to each `order_products` item.  I have the `imgURL`, but I want to add a `processedImgUrl` and stub it with `true` right now.  How can I add the field to the above php function when returning the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the dataset this may not be exactly accurate but the way to do this is either to perform an array push or do a foreach loop and add create the index to be appended.

For example:

```
public function newFlavorOrders()
{   
    // CREATE A NEW ARRAY TO ADD THE MODIFIED DATA TO
    $modified = array();
    $orders = request()->user()->ordersPaid;

    // LOOP THROUGH AND ADD THE VALUE TO THE ITERATION
    foreach($orders as $row) {
        foreach($row['order_products'] as $val){
            $modified = $val;
            if(!empty($val['imgUrl'])){
                $modified['processedImgUrl'] = TRUE;
            } else {
                $modified['processedImgUrl'] = FALSE;
            }
        }
    }

    return response()->json(['flavor_orders' => $modified]);
}
```

Something like this should work. You need to loop through the first array, then get down to the next level array (order_products).

Comment: thanks @enoch but the new value needs to be in the nested array (above), for each `order_products` ...that's the part I'm having trouble with

Comment: You will need to do 2 loops to get the desired result, let me edit my code

Answer (score 0):

```
public function newFlavorOrders()
    {
        $orders = request()->user()->ordersPaid;

        $orders = $orders->map(function ($order) {

            $order->order_products = $order->order_products->map(function ($products) {
                $products['processedImgUrl'] = true;
                return $products;
            });

            return $order;
        });

        return response()->json(['flavor_orders' => $orders]);
    }
```